# Java & High CPU usage

Tags: java, cpu, temperature, cpu-load

I use a certain java application to trade the stock market and it consumes 90% my CPU power. And the CPU temp usually remains around 90c. This is a real headache. **What causes this problem and what are the possible solutions?**

Thank you.